# Retrieve Specific Files from Directory Using FTP

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm creating a C# application that needs to FTP to a directory to retrieve a file list. The following code works just fine. However, the folder that I'm FTPing to contains around 92,000 files. This code will not work in the way that I want it to for a file list of that size.

I'm looking only for files that begin with the string "c-". After doing some research, I'm not even sure how to begin trying to solve this issue. Is there any way I can modify this existing code for it to retrieve only those files?

```
public string[] getFileList() {
    string[] downloadFiles;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    FtpWebRequest reqFTP;

    try {
        reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpHost));
        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPass);
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        WebResponse response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        while (line != null) {
            result.Append(line);
            result.Append("\n");
            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        // to remove the trailing '\n'
        result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
        return result.ToString().Split('\n');
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        downloadFiles = null;
        return downloadFiles;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you looked into regular expressions?

Comment: @RobertH - I did think regular expressions might be the way to go, but the issue is actually retrieving the file list to parse with regular expressions. It'll just hang.

Comment: I am not familiar with the FTP classes per se, but assuming that line includes your filename ( and likely extra stuff to ) what about splitting your string based on spaces, or whatever control character is present and then passing the resulting filename through a regex and adding it to results if it matches the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `LIST` doesn't support wildcard search and in fact it might be vary from different FTP platform and depend the COMMANDS support

you will need to download all the files name in the FTP directory using `LIST` , probably in the async way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative implementation along the similar lines. I've tested this with as many as 1000 ftp files, it might work for you. Complete source code can be found [here](http://libftp.codeplex.com).

```
    public List<ftpinfo> browse(string path) //eg: "ftp.xyz.org", "ftp.xyz.org/ftproot/etc"
    {
        FtpWebRequest request=(FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(path);
        request.Method=WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
        List<ftpinfo> files=new List<ftpinfo>();

        //request.Proxy = System.Net.WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
        //request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_username, _password);
        Stream rs=(Stream)request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

        OnStatusChange("CONNECTED: " + path, 0, 0);

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs);
        string strList = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] lines=null;

        if (strList.Contains("\r\n"))
        {
            lines=strList.Split(new string[] {"\r\n"},StringSplitOptions.None);
        }
        else if (strList.Contains("\n"))
        {
            lines=strList.Split(new string[] {"\n"},StringSplitOptions.None);
        }

        //now decode this string array

        if (lines==null || lines.Length == 0)
            return null;

        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Length==0)
                continue;
            //parse line
            Match m= GetMatchingRegex(line);
            if (m==null) {
                //failed
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to parse line: " + line);
            }

            ftpinfo item=new ftpinfo();
            item.filename = m.Groups["name"].Value.Trim('\r');
            item.path = path;
            item.size = Convert.ToInt64(m.Groups["size"].Value);
            item.permission = m.Groups["permission"].Value;
            string _dir = m.Groups["dir"].Value;
            if(_dir.Length>0  && _dir != "-")
            {
                item.fileType = directoryEntryTypes.directory;
            } 
            else
            {
                item.fileType = directoryEntryTypes.file;
            }

            try
            {
                item.fileDateTime = DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["timestamp"].Value);
            }
            catch
            {
                item.fileDateTime = DateTime.MinValue; //null;
            }

            files.Add(item);
        }

        return files;
    }
```